# LWC recordId is not defined

Tags: lightning-web-components, salesforcedx

I am receiving the following error *recordId is not defined* when simply trying to display the record id on the page (for debugging). What I want to do is append the id of the record page to a string as seen below.

I also tried with {$recordId} but that did not work. Any suggestions?

HTML:

```
<template>
 <lightning-card  title="App" icon-name="custom:custom59">
    <div class="slds-m-around_medium">
        <iframe width="800" height={hight} src={fullUrl}> </iframe>
    </div>    
 </lightning-card>
</template>
```

JS:

```
import { LightningElement, api } from 'lwc';

export default class App extends LightningElement {
  @api recordId;
  @api height;
  url = 'http://example.com/'+{recordId};

  get fullUrl() {
    alert("id is: " + {recordId});
    return this.url;
  }
}
```

MetaData

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <apiVersion>48.0</apiVersion>
    <isExposed>true</isExposed>
    <masterLabel>App</masterLabel>
    <targets>
        <target>lightning__RecordPage</target>
        <target>lightning__HomePage</target>
        <target>lightning__Tab</target>
    </targets>
    <targetConfigs>
        <targetConfig targets="lightning__RecordPage, lightning__HomePage">
        <property name="height" type="Integer" default="50" label="Enter the height of Iframe"/>
        </targetConfig>
    </targetConfigs>
</LightningComponentBundle>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You can not use expression while defining the property, use connectedCallback to set the default values.
2. inside the function do not use `{property}`, use `this.property` instead.

See the corrected code below.

```js
url;

connectedCallback(){
    this.url = 'http://example.com/' + this.recordId;
}

get fullUrl() {
    alert("id is: " + this.recordId);
    return this.url;
}
```